# drush default site alias

Tags: drush

Is there a way of specifying a default site alias ?

couldnt find it in [drushrc example](http://drush.ws/examples/example.drushrc.php) nor [aliases example](http://drush.ws/examples/example.aliases.drushrc.php).

**motivation**
i am sclerotic and lazy :) usually running drush from the dir where the site is, so no alias needed. Now working in a setup where i am logged in on a different server then the actual site, so i need to always provide a site alias for each command. So the usual workflow is:

```
drush wipe
oh no
drush @stage wipe
```

so i thought a default site alias would save me from those two lines :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Drush automatically defines the alias @self to refer to the currently bootstrapped site.  So, if you have identified a site via cwd (that is, `cd /path/to/sites/mysite`, where `sites/mysite` is the folder that contains settings.php), then you could run:

```
drush sa @self
```

This will tell Drush to print out a site alias for the current site. You can then copy this to an alias file and give it a handy name for later use.  If you're doing this for a remote site, try adding --with-db if you'd like to include the database record inside the site alias.  You're better off leaving out the database information for local sites, though, as you can get inconsistent results if the db info in your alias does not match the db info in settings.php.

If you want to disable cwd-based site selection, then define 'root' and 'uri' in any drushrc.php file:

```
$options['root'] = '/path/to/drupal';
$options['uri'] = 'http://mysite.org';
```

There is no way to specify an alias in a Drush configuration file, but you could use the `site-set` command from the command line:

```
$ drush site-set @stage
```

If you wanted this command to be persistent, you could run it from your .bashrc.

Comment: thanks, interesting, unfortunately not solving my problem ... i edited the question to explain what i am doing, hopefully its clearer now :)

Comment: Okay, I added a bit to my answer to cover your intended question. :)

Answer (score 2):

It is also possible to set default uri in settings.php inside the root of your drupal folder.

Like this:

```
$base_url = 'http://localhost/...';
```

Then you don't need to update your drushrc.php file every time you start a new project.