# "No Drupal site found" -- Windows and SQL Server

Tags: database, drush, multi-sites, bootstrapping

So I'm trying to upgrade our system from using Drush 6 to Drush 8, as that is the currently supported version of Drush that supports Drupal 7. I have managed to get drush working, however it does not recognize any of our environments as a Drupal environment.

If I run `drush cc all` I get back:

> No Drupal site found, only 'drush' cache was cleared.

If I run any other Drush command (from my sites directory) I get back:

> Command 'command' needs a higher bootstrap level to run.

Running `drush status` returns no DB information at all.

Now there seems to be quite a few questions out there like this, and lots of recommended solutions, but nothing is pertinent to my environment. I'm using IIS on a Windows Server machine, with SQL Server (not MySQL), so none of the solutions are applicable. I'm wondering if anyone has any ideas for solving this within my current environment?

---

Keeping in mind, all of these environments worked fine with no issue prior to upgrading to Drush 8 (using Drush 6).

Output of `drush -v status`:

```
Loading outputformat engine.                                 [notice]
 PHP configuration      :  "C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\5.6.26\php.ini"
 PHP OS                 :  WINNT
 Drush script           :  location/of/drush
 Drush version          :  8.1.13
 Drush temp directory   :  temp/location
 Drush configuration    :
 Drush alias files      :
Command dispatch complete                                    [notice]
```

`settings.php` file database settings:

```
$databases['default']['default'] = array(
  'database' => 'databasename',
  'username' => 'username',
  'password' => 'password',
  'host' => 'hostName',
  'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
);
```

---

Executing `drush sql-connect` command returns:

> Unable to load class `Drush\Sql\Sql`.
>
> Unable to find matching SQL Class.
>
> Drush cannot find your database connection details.

I should also mention that `drush site-install` works fine, it's just running Drush inside a newly created area that doesn't work.

---

To clarify, I am using a multi-tenant install, so I have multiple tenants such as `sites/tenant`, `sites/tenant2`, `sites/tenant3`, etc.

For example I am running `drush` from the `sites/tenant` directory and Drush doesn't recognise my Drupal installation. Traditionally, before updating, I could run `drush` from inside any of those and everything would work.

Comment: @kenorb edited my original post to include that

Comment: @kenorb Pasted database settings into original post. Yes, I can confirm the existence of all those files. The link doesn't really apply. Everything worked fine within Windows Server, IIS, and SQL Server before I upgraded Drush from version 6 to version 8. I'm using the sqlsrv module for my connection.

Comment: @kenorb Yes I can confirm that the command exists globally and can be run from anywhere via the command line.

Comment: @kenorb I get the following error running that. Unable to load class Drush\Sql\Sql. And 'Unable to find matching SQL Class. Drush cannot find your database connection details.'. I should also mention that drush site-install works fine, it's just running Drush inside a newly created area that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This patch worked for me, https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/pull/3000.

For reference this is the fix, within Drush, in includes/environment.inc, add this line:

```
$path = str_replace('/', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $path);
```

Just before:

```
$path = explode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $path);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should perform the following checks:

- For *SQL Server*, review README file of [SQL Server driver for Drupal 7](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/sqlsrv/tree/README.txt?h=7.x-2.x) to confirm the right requirements and installation steps. See also: [Can I use MS SQL with Drupal](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/171772/1908).
- Make sure that your database client (such as `sqlcmd`) command exists globally (from the command-line). Otherwise make sure its path is added into your PATH system variable. See: [`Sqlsqlsrv.php`](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/blob/8.x/lib/Drush/Sql/Sqlsqlsrv.php).
- Clear Drush internal caches and try again:

  ```
  drush cc drush
  ```
- If you're using a multisite environment, make sure to specify the right Drupal site to use, e.g.

  ```
  drush --uri=http://site1.example.com status
  ```

  or:

  ```
  drush -l http://site2.example.com status
  ```

  <sup>Note: By default Drush uses `sites/default` unless you will run the command in specific `sites/` folder.</sup>

  <sup>Note: To define URI of the Drupal site, set `$base_url` in your settings file per given site (or [`drushrc.php`](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/121979/1908)).</sup>
- Run `drush status` (add `-d` for debugging output) to check whether `Drupal root`, `Database name` and `Database driver` has been detected correctly. If not, run the command again, but in the same folder where is your `settings.php` file and verify that `Drupal Settings File` has been recognized. Verify it has the right read permissions
- Check the output of `drush sql-connect` command whether it returns the right command and there are no errors.

  If there is no matching *SQL Class*, this suggests `drush` can't detect the db driver from your settings file. So confirm the following command returns the current site path (folder containing `settings.php`):

  ```
  drush ev "echo drush_site_path();"
  ```

  If it's empty, make sure you're running `drush` command in the right folder and your `settings.php` exists.
- Check whether Drupal bootstrap object is properly loaded by:

  ```
  drush ev "print_r(drush_get_bootstrap_object());"
  ```

  If so, check whether your settings file is readable:

  ```
  drush ev 'echo file_get_contents(drush_get_bootstrap_object()->conf_path()."/settings.php");
  ```

  Otherwise if your bootstrap object is *EmptyBoot*, please review how Drush defines Drupal root as valid ([candidates](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/blob/8.x/includes/bootstrap.inc#L144) are: [`DrupalBoot6`](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/blob/8.x/lib/Drush/Boot/DrupalBoot6.php), [`DrupalBoot7`](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/blob/8.x/lib/Drush/Boot/DrupalBoot7.php), [`DrupalBoot8`](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/blob/8.x/lib/Drush/Boot/DrupalBoot8.php)), for Drupal 7 the logic is as below:

  ```
  function valid_root($path) {
    if (!empty($path) && is_dir($path) && file_exists($path . '/index.php')) {
      // Drupal 7 root.
      // We check for the presence of 'modules/field/field.module' to differentiate this from a D6 site
      $candidate = 'includes/common.inc';
      if (file_exists($path . '/' . $candidate) && file_exists($path . '/misc/drupal.js') && file_exists($path . '/modules/field/field.module')) {
        return $candidate;
      }
    }
  }
  ```

  So make sure that you've the following files present: `includes/common.inc`, `misc/drupal.js` and `modules/field/field.module` in your Drupal root (where `$path` is your Drupal root, but it can be specified manually by `--root=path/to/drupal`). Also make sure the files are readable by the user (in case of symlinks, they're pointing to the right files; right permissions in case of [network share](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php#76194) or Linux file system). Otherwise edit Drupal boot class file (e.g. [`DrupalBoot7.php`](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/blob/8.x/lib/Drush/Boot/DrupalBoot7.php), part of Drush) and try to debug the above `valid_root()` method by checking which condition exactly fails and why.

  Example Drush command to verify whether `index.php` exists:

  ```
  drush ev '$path = drush_get_context("DRUSH_SELECTED_DRUPAL_ROOT"); var_dump(file_exists($path . "/index.php"));'
  ```
- Finally check whether SQL class can be loaded by:

  ```
  drush ev 'var_dump(drush_sql_get_class());'
  ```
- You may consider re-testing in different PHP versions, e.g.

#### Debugging

Assuming `drush status` doesn't return the right details, here are the suggested steps to debug drush (shell commands).

1. Install and enable [PHP `xdebug` extension](https://xdebug.org/). Verify by `php71 -i | grep xdebug`.

   <sup>Consider these xdebug ini settings: [`xdebug.ini`](https://github.com/kenorb/kenorb/blob/master/conf/php/xdebug.ini) for better visibility.</sup>
2. On empty folder, install clean Drupal, e.g.

   ```
   drush -y qd --no-server --core=drupal-8
   cd quick-drupal-*/drupal*
   ```
3. Verify *Drupal root*, *Settings File* and *Database* are present in `drush status`.
4. Generate trace file for the working bootstrap process:

   ```
   drush ev "xdebug_start_trace(); print_r(_core_site_status_table()); echo xdebug_get_tracefile_name(); xdebug_stop_trace();"
   ```

   <sup>If xdebug is enabled for different PHP version, specify with `DRUSH_PHP=/path/to/php`.</sup>

   If successful, trace output file should be printed at the end, so take a note of it.
5. Generate another trace file for the same command above, but in the location which doesn't work.
6. Now compare these two trace files (working with non-working) using some diff tool (*Meld*, *DiffMerge*, *`opendiff`*, etc.) and check the differences. For better format, remove first 40 columns from these files (e.g. `ex +'%norm 40dl' -scwq file.xt`).

---

If you believe you found a Drush bug, please report it with details at [GitHub issue page](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/issues).

Comment: drush_site_path returns the correct path to the site folder. However drush_get_bootstrap_object just returns ``Drush\Boot\EmptyBoot Object``, which I believe is likely where my problem lies. Looking up that specific issue gives me lots of issues with Drupal 8 which I'm not using, I'm using Drupal 7 with PHP 5.6.

Comment: @ArakTai'Roth If you've got _EmptyBoot_, that means `valid_root()` method in `DrupalBoot7` class failed to detect your Drupal root. Check the details in the updated answer to review what could be the case as you could be missing one of the files.

Comment: So, I went into that function you gave me (thanks by the way) and did some debugging. Apparently $path is being set to ``C:/longListOfDirectories/sites/tenant`` where tenant is my sites folder. The files exist in my Drupal install, but not at that location, they exist at two levels above that, just above ``/sites``. That's likely my issue, how would I go about permanently changing what directory Drush references? By the way, this is a multi-tenant install, which might be part of the issue.

Comment: @ArakTai'Roth Then you need to run `drush` in `sites/tenant`, or use `-l` or `--uri` parameter, e.g. `drush -l http://tenant.example.com status`. I've updated the answer.

Comment: I am running from the ``sites/tenant`` directory. I have multiple tenants ``sites/tenant2``, ``sites/tenant3`` etc.... Traditionally, before updating, I could run drush from inside any of those and everything would work. But as I said above, it appears that in the function ``valid_root``, ``$path`` is set to the tenant directory, not the directory of my Drupal install which is just above ``sites``, it's looking two levels too deep for the files and thus not finding them and thus returning an EmptyObject.

Comment: @ArakTai'Roth It could be a Drush bug (regression), so you can [report one](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/issues). Ideally if you could create some minimal reproducible scenario to demonstrate the problem. First test Drush 8.1-dev to make sure if it's not already fixed.